# How to remove 'at' from formatted date string?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

This is the date formatter setup:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
```

Expected output:

```
Aug 13, 2017 6:04:11 PM
```

Current output:

```
Aug 13, 2017 at 6:04:11 PM
```

How can the 'at' word be removed ideally without specifying a format string and where does it come from?

With Austrian German locale:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_AT")
13.08.2017, 18:04:11
```

With US English locale:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
Aug 13, 2017 at 6:04:11 PM
```

Comment: What is your current locale? Or do you use also the `dateFormat` property?

Comment: @vadian I’ve just extended the posting with the locale information. The ‘at’ seems to come from the English locale. I don’t use the dateFormat property.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can achieve the expected output using

`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a"`.

The `at` word is put there due to the current locale, so if you want to get rid of it for all locales, you should specify the exact date format as you can see above.

Comment: That would give `Aug. 13, 2017 6:22:48 PM` for the german locale, which does not "look right" :)

Comment: It's poor practice to hardcode a specific date and time format. This results in a very unexpected date and time for most users in various locales.

Answer (score 9):

One option would be to make two separate conversions, one 
setting only `dateStyle = .medium`, and one setting only 
`timeStyle = .medium`, and then concatenate the result. But I don't know
if a

```
<date><space><time>
```

format makes sense in all languages and locales.

A better approach is to use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`:

```
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM dd yyyy jj:mm:ss")
```

This comes close to what you wanted, and is guaranteed to give a 
sensible result for all locale settings. Here some examples.

```
en_US:   Aug 13, 2017, 6:33:54 PM
de:      13. Aug. 2017, 18:33:54
ja:      2017年8月13日 18:33:54
```

Note the usage of `jj` format for the hour, this will be interpreted
as `HH` (24 hour format) or `hh` (12 hour AM/PM format), depending
on the locale.

Comment: That looks good! But I’d like to avoid specifying a format string and find out where ‘at’ comes from.

Comment: @AndrasHatvani Then please answer the question posted by vadian just below your question.

Comment: @AndrasHatvani:  The "at" is part of the locale. (NS)DateFormatter ultimately uses the "ICU library for Unicode". The relevant part could be `ures_getStringByIndex(dateTimePatterns.getAlias(), glueIndex, &resStrLen, &status);` in http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/trunk/icu4c/source/i18n/smpdtfmt.cpp. I don't know if that "glue" is configurable, but I doubt it.

Comment: @AndrasHatvani: As I understand it from that ICU source code, "date" and "time" are glued together with a locale dependent string. Therefore doing two separate conversions (my first suggestion) would give the same result without the glue string.

Answer (score -2):

You can write it to a string and use text.Replace to replace it with nothing.

Comment: That would work only for certain locales. The string can e.g. be `13.08.2017, 18:18:33` in the German locale.